# No errors if constructor arguments are missing

Tags: typescript

That compiles without errors:

```
interface A {}

interface AConstructor {
  new(id: string): A
}


const AC: AConstructor = class implements A {
  // note the missing parameter »id«
  constructor(){}
}
```

But changing to:

```
const AC: AConstructor = class implements A {
  // note that this is now of type number
  constructor(id: number){}
}
```

Creates an error. All in all there are no errors if constructor parameters are missing, only if they are of the wrong type. Why is that? Is there any flag to make TS create a compile error if those arguments are missing?

Comment: [Partly it's because of this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters). It's valid to have a function with *less* arguments.